# How do I use JavaScriptSerializer in ASP.NET 5?

Tags: asp.net-core, appsettings, javascriptserializer, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I am porting my project to `DNX-Core 5.0` and trying to get work but I cannot find the `JavaScriptSerializer` and `AppSettingReader` classes.  I know the `System.Web` is removed and so please anyone help me to find the alternative of using them.

Is there any Nuget available to include them?

Answer (score 7):

The ASP.Net 5 team dropped the `JavaScriptSerializer` in favor of the widely used `Newtonsoft.Json` package, but they did provide a [JsonOutputFormatter](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/39fe063aeec41bec2d93eaea3cfcc66c2b8c493d/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/Formatters/JsonOutputFormatter.cs) and a [JsonInputFormatter](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/39fe063aeec41bec2d93eaea3cfcc66c2b8c493d/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/Formatters/JsonInputFormatter.cs) for use with MVC to be able to return objects more directly.

For the `AppSettingReader` you'll want to look at the new [ASP.Net 5 Configuration Model](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration). This has been detailed in a [few](http://whereslou.com/2014/05/23/asp-net-vnext-moving-parts-iconfiguration/) blog [posts](http://blog.jsinh.in/asp-net-5-configuration-microsoft-framework-configurationmodel/) while it's being built. These posts only detail how to load out individual fields, but the tests in the [Options Model](https://github.com/aspnet/Options/) show that you can [bind directly to an object.](https://github.com/aspnet/Options/blob/dev/test/Microsoft.Framework.OptionsModel.Test/OptionsTest.cs)

Comment: Plus one for using Options instead of Configuration