# ScriptIgnore ASP 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to ignore a field when I am converting my object into a json string. I saw on Internet that I have to use [ScriptIgnore] on my field. But I can't find any way to import the System.Web.Script...

i'm using this :

```
"dependencies": {
"AutoMapper": "4.2.1",
"EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
"Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
},
```

Is this because this is incompatible due to the MVC 6 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on 'References' in solution explorer then select 'Add References..' - you will need to add `System.Web.Extensions` from Assemblies - DNX 4.5.1 to your solution.

Note you may then get compiler error about `DNX Core 5.0` which is a lightweight version of the framework optimized for cloud. If you do not need to support it just remove from "frameworks" in `project.json`.

```
 // comment out or delete.
 "dnxcore50": { }
```

Just for future reference if you look up the relevant [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation it shows which **Assembly** you need to include.

Comment: Err, this is weird. I remember doing a thing like this.. Nevermind. Thank you James ;)

Comment: There has *got* to be some other way of doing this without resorting to pulling in `System.Web`.  Maybe it's another attribute, or else a whole different approach...

Answer (score 11):

Without resorting to `System.Web`, which I think is good to avoid:

Since MVC has [switched formatters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30260173/268066), you should now use `[JsonIgnore]` (from `Newtonsoft.Json`) instead of `[ScriptIgnore]`.

Oh and if you're doing this to prevent reference loops, do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36633265/268066

Answer (score 1):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters; 

public class Page 

{

public int Id { get; set; }

public int Number { get; set; }

public int? BookId { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore)]

public Book Book{ get; set; }

}

////////////////

public class Book
{

public int Id { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Page> Pages { get;set;}

}
```

Comment: Please include more context/explanation