# Analog JavaScriptSerializer.ConvertToType in .Net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, .net-core-rc2

Please help to find analog JavaScriptSerializer.ConvertToType(object obj, Type targetType) in .Net core

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net vnext5 - cannot find JavaScriptSerializer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239683/asp-net-vnext5-cannot-find-javascriptserializer)

Comment: I know that some functionality move from  JavaScriptSerializer to Newtonsoft.Json in the .Net Core. But I can't find ConvertToType there

Comment: This link may be useful for you https://thedevstop.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/from-javascriptserializer-to-jsonnet/